# dotNetRdf Query to Sparql endpoint not working

Tags: sparql, dotnetrdf

I am struggeling to run Sparql queries from within my .NET 7 application.

First, I am configuring my `HttpClient` in `Program.cs`

```
services.AddHttpClient("sparql", httpClient =>
        {
            var url = context.Configuration.GetSection("Sparql").GetValue<string>("EndpointUrl");
            var header = context.Configuration.GetSection("Sparql").GetValue<string>("AuthorizationHeaderValue");

            httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://.../query");
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(HeaderNames.Authorization, header);
        });
```

Then, I do the following to send a query:

```
string query = @"...";

var endpoint = new VDS.RDF.Query.SparqlQueryClient(_client, new Uri("https://.../query"));
SparqlConnector connector = new SparqlConnector(endpoint);

Object results = connector.Query(query);
```

I am getting what looks like a timeout exception after a longer period of waiting. (The query is limited to 10 results, this should not be the issue.)

I have also been looking here: https://dotnetrdf.org/docs/2.7.x/user_guide/Triple-Store-Integration.html#query

This would work but here, I am lacking the possibility to specify my Basic Authentication header.

Any hints on this would be greatly appreciated.

**Update**
I am using dotNetRdf Version 3.0.0, which was released in spring of this year. The documentation does not seem to be up to date throughout.

Comment: A query that does operations like ORDER BY or some GROUP/aggregation may have to evaluate the whole query pattern before knowing which are the first 10 results.

Comment: If I execute the query in YASGUI it takes only milliseconds to complete.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a working solution after some digging.

```
var endpoint = new VDS.RDF.Query.SparqlQueryClient(_myHttpClient, new Uri("https://.../query"));

var result = await endpoint.QueryWithResultSetAsync(myQuery);
```

Turns out that you don't need an instance of `SparqlConnector` to query the endpoint.